# DIN Alternate font

Tags: web-fonts, font-licensing

I want to use a DIN Alternate font in a web application, however I couldn't find any license information about it. Does it also differ from FF DIN?

UPD:
I also have a .ttf file which states copyright of Linotype, however I also couldn't find anything regarding this typeface on their site.

Answer (score 1):

On inspection of the font "DIN Alternate" which is offered as "free" on various dubious websites, I was able to extract this information from the font file itself:

> ©Dutch Design: Albert-Jan Pool, 1995. Published by FontShop
>   International FontFont release
>   15DIN-RegularAlternateDINRegularAlternate

So, yes it would seem to be copyright, and I would assume you need to buy a licence.  So, contact [the publisher](https://www.fontshop.com/)

Some of these free font sites don't seem to care if fonts are offered legally or not, which is why I would never use them.  Other more responsible free font sites do display the licences, such as dafont, and fontlibrary.  My suggestion would be only to use sites which actually refer to the licences.

One of these so-called "free" font sites, which I shall not name, offers this laughable disclaimer.

> By downloading fonts from our site or using them you agree you have
>   read and understood that the font or dingbat copyrights belongs to the
>   designer of the related product. In cases where there are no copyright
>   notices, you need to assume that the font is copyrighted. Use of the
>   fonts is at your sole responsibility. We do not take any
>   responsibility and we are not liable for any damage caused through use
>   of the fonts . . .

Comment: Its not actually possible to track the copyright info of things very easily. By Design it builds on assumption that nothing is free. So unless you have a explicit license saying something is free, or you have a archived copy of your purchase. Then it is not possible be sure.